# Flash - Record user's action and save as movie

Tags: flash

I am developing a small flash application. In my application a user can draw a painting. I want to capture the drawing process as a video, and later allow him to view how he painted the drawing. Is such a thing possbile? If so how (do I need flash media server for this)?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in a direct way you'll need something like FLV encoder solution from inside of flash application, but it will be too hard.

in a second way you may use some server instance (FlashMediaServer/Red5/Wowza/Stratus) to record events (read as Whiteboard Application)

So you will able to show to end-user his actions like an animation, not exactly as movie, but just an application with messages from your server, and their playback. Something like this.

in all other cases you will need GIF Encoder to produce some huge animation file, look google for it. http://google.com/?q=flex+GIF+encoder

Comment: so what you suggest is to send to the server every few miliseconds or so a print screen of the current screen status and create an animation based on it?

Comment: if you are looking for some little time animation I will advice a GIF client-based creation as cheap and productivity solution. If you need big sizes & quality & sharing with other users - use server based solution. As I said go throw the whiteboard solution based on RTMP servers.